# Is there anyway that I could find the time that an element takes to load using selenium webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, performance-testing, ui-automation

I need to find the time that an element takes to load and it's ready to be accessible. As I've so many explicit 'sleep' in my script, I'm trying to reduce it by using the metric.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What kind of element is that? Why is it not ready / accessible at first? Is JavaScript involved?

Comment: I'm not fighting to access the element. I want to know the time it takes to get loaded. Lets say I've a script for login, When I execute it, the script passes username and pwd and clicks Login. That's all fine, but what i want to know is that, I want the time it took to load the elements login and pwd.

Comment: So you can adjust the `sleep` amount in your script, right? Chances are the time it takes for the element(s) to become available is not constant.

Comment: Erm, I've only used Selenium in Java but I imagine the functionality should still be present in ruby - there is a `wait` element you can use and wait _for_ something using `wait.until`. It supports stuff like waiting until an element is loaded, or waiting until it's visible or waiting until it's _not_ visible. Essentially, you pass a predicate and Selenium will do the sleep-check-sleep cycle for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an Implicit Wait so that the webdriver polls the dom until the element appears.

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10 # seconds
```

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp